# Is execstack available on ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, apt

I see this command. Is it available on Ubuntu?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/execstack.htm

Answer (score 3):

It is not installed by default, but it can be installed.  Looks like it is in the `Universe` repository.  As long as it is enabled you should be able to install it.  If it is not enabled you can enable it with the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

Then you can try the command by itself to see if it is already installed.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ execstack

Command 'execstack' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install execstack
```

Usually when `apt` knows that the command can be found in a package in the Ubuntu repositories, it will list what package you need to install and it is not necessarily the name of the command.  Below I have gone ahead and installed it.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install execstack
[sudo] password for terrance: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  execstack
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 74.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 233 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 execstack amd64 0.0.20131005-1 [74.4 kB]
Fetched 74.4 kB in 0s (156 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package execstack.
(Reading database ... 631244 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../execstack_0.0.20131005-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking execstack (0.0.20131005-1) ...
Setting up execstack (0.0.20131005-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ execstack
execstack: no files given
```

Below is from the `rmadison` script showing all versions of `execstack` available in the Ubuntu repositories.  *Note: `rmadison` will only show from the Ubuntu repositories and no third party repositories if you decide to use them.*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ rmadison execstack
 execstack | 0.0.20090925-1   | precise          | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 execstack | 0.0.20090925-8   | trusty           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 execstack | 0.0.20130503-1.1 | xenial/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 execstack | 0.0.20131005-1   | bionic/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 execstack | 0.0.20131005-1   | focal/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 execstack | 0.0.20131005-1.1 | groovy/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 execstack | 0.0.20131005-1.1 | hirsute/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Comment: Link to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fexecstack would very useful too. Because package name and executable name are not always same.

Comment: @N0rbert In this case the command up in my example was pretty straight forward about it being installed with the `sudo apt package`, but I agree with you that not every command is the same as the package name.  =)